# Comparing time in excel that's formatted as text (includes negative time)

Tags: datetime, excel-formula, excel-2007, logical-operators, text-parsing

Need to filter all rows that have a negative time or a time less than 20 hours. Length of time drops to as low as -300 hours. Because I'm importing this data, it imports as `=TEXT("-20:42","[h]:mm")` or `=TEXT("3:29","[h]:mm")`

Creating a custom filter produced 0 outputs.

Right now, I added a column to my table with this formula

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("-*",Table15[[#This Row],[Resolve Time To Go]])),"Breech", "No Breech")`

This works fine for the negative values, but I'm having difficulty pulling the values between 0 and 20 hours.

This formula returns true for positive values, but doesn't stop at 20

```
=IF(VALUE(Table15[[#This Row],[Resolve Time To Go]])<TIMEVALUE(20), "Breech", "No Breech")
```

I don't mind if I have to create a couple extra columns to get this data as I'll just be using it for pivot tables, however it would be nice if it could be done in 1 column. I tried merging the 2 functions but I got a pop-up saying there were too many logical statements (?).

This will also eventually need to be included in a macro.

Comment: I think that you should approach the problem more directly.  That is use a numeric value for the pivot column representing time, instead of a text value.

Comment: @ergohack I did consider that but I haven't figured out how to reformat this data as a numeric value (especially the negative hours)

=TEXT("-31:40","[h]:mm")

Answer (score 2):

If you have in column **A** time-as-text values, then in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="-",-TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,2,99)),TIMEVALUE(A1))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

As you see from the picture above, if you want to display only times greater than or equal to 20 hours, set AutoFilter on the helper column to be greater than or equal to .8333333

All small and negative times will be hidden.

**EDIT#1:**

Once the hours exceed 24, `TIMEVALUE()` becomes unreliable.  Therefor this should be used instead:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="-",-TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,2,99)),LEFT(A1,2)/24+RIGHT(A1,2)/(24*60))
```

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work but only up to 24 hours. The output is increasing linearly from -300 to 24, but then jumps from 0.99 to 0.068 after 24 (my data set goes from around -300 to +300 hours)

Comment: @FT2417  I will see if a fix is possible

Comment: @FT2417  See my **EDIT#1**